# Adding two fields from two different modules django module

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’m making a stock management app where I would like to add a class field `quantity` (value) with a `quantity_prod` field from module `ProductionArticle`. The result of this operation should populate another field `quantity_in_stock` in the class `Article`.

I have tried the annotate with the F expression and the override save method with article_set but I don’t find a good result I’m wondering if there is a direct method to make mathematic operation between fields without using a complex method

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default='0216')
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices_unite, default='')
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    quantity_in_stock = models.FloatField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation

class ProductionArticle(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    planned quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    production date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date d'ajout")
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices_unite, default='')
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Ahmed')
    quantity_prod  = models.FloatField(defaut=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `F` is appropriate here. Because an `Article` object can have multiple `ProductionArticle`. Instead, use [**`Sum`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

articles = Article.objects.annotate(prod_quantity=Sum('productarticle__quantity_prod')).annotate(quantity_in_stock=F('prod_quantity')+F('quantity'))

for a in articles:
   print(a.quantity_in_stock)
```

An alternative to above solution is to use a property method. But it is not recommended because it will increase DB hits:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def quantity_in_stock(self):
        return self.productionarticle_set.all().aggregate(qsum=Coalesce(Sum('quantity_prod'), 0))['qsum'] + self.quantity
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn’t clear I would like for each article his quantity_in_stock is equal to quantity produced (quantity_prod) and his quantity in the initial stock example the article 1 have the quantity_in_stock1 = quantity_prod1 + quantity1 @ruddra

Comment: for the second method (@property) it through error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: I guess I have to initiate the qsum  to zero                         'qsum=Sum('quantity_prod'))['qsum'] or 0.0'

Comment: yep, that will work, also please see the updated answer